# Fatal error: Acrobat failed to connect to DDE server

Tags: windows, pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader, dde

This is my problem: I can always open one PDF document in Acrobat Reader from Explorer, and sometimes more (especially soon after Windows restart). However, after some time it starts to fail: when I double-click a PDF file, there is no immediate reaction, and some time later I get an error dialog saying

> Fatal error: Acrobat failed to connect to DDE server

I can open files without problem: 1) from Explorer after closing all other instances of Acrobat Reader; 2) from Acrobat Reader's `File > Open` menu.

Googling shows many forum threads about this error. However, most are about problems working over network; this is on my personal computer. Disabling "Enable protected mode at startup" works for some people, but not in my case.

Comment: Got the same problem. How can a software company release such a flawed version ...

Comment: I am getting this same issue. I found 2 solutions, and neither of them worked.  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/failed-to-connect-to-dde-server.html directed me to edit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\acrobat\shell\open\ddeexec\application from "AcroviewA18" to "AcroviewR18".  Unfortunately, my registry already had "AcroviewR18".  The other solution listed was to disable AV, that had no effect.